# Angular / Meteor: Array is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, mongodb, meteor

I'm building an Angular / Meteor application, using Meteor's reactivity to populated an Angular model. It is all working fine until I start working with arrays.

```
// get sentence
$scope.sentence = $meteor.object(Sentences, $stateParams.sentenceId);

// related sentences
$scope.relatedSentences = $meteor.collection(function() {
   return Sentences.find({_id: { $in: $scope.sentence.relatedSentences }}); 
});
```

I get this error on the JavaScript console

```
Error: $in needs an array
    at Error (native)
    at Object.ELEMENT_OPERATORS.$in.compileElementSelector     (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:1894:15)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:1576:19
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?    0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)
```

In the Mongo / Meteor console

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.sentences.find({_id: "sp75iWPNqpbp2ypmy"});
{ "_id" : "sp75iWPNqpbp2ypmy", "sentence" : "Here is sentence 1 ", "language" : "en", "level" : "A1", "public" : true, "relatedSentences" : [ "wNs4ByDq7t396WLM3" ] }
```

And

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.sentences.find({_id: { $in: [ "wNs4ByDq7t396WLM3" ] }});  
{ "_id" : "wNs4ByDq7t396WLM3", "sentence" : "Here is sentence 0 ", "language" : "en", "level" : "A1", "public" : true, "relatedSentences" : [ ] }
```

I then commented out the failing find and have outputted the objects to html

```
$scope.sentence = $meteor.object(Sentences, $stateParams.sentenceId);
$scope.test = typeof $scope.sentence.relatedSentences;

Sentence: {{sentence}}<br/>
Related: {{sentence.relatedSentences}}<br/>
Typeof: {{test}}
```

Results

```
Sentence: {"autorunComputation":    {"stopped":false,"invalidated":false,"firstRun":false,"_id":47,"_onInvalidateCallbacks":  [null,null],"_parent":null,"_recomputing":false},"_id":"oFMp7swYyQsXkYsKz","sent ence":"Here is sentence  2","language":"en","level":"A1","public":true,"relatedSentences":    ["wNs4ByDq7t396WLM3"]}
Related: ["wNs4ByDq7t396WLM3"]
Typeof: undefined
```

**The Array is marked as undefined**, but it is clearly shown in the full object. What am I missing?

**EDIT** 
When running the above test on Firefox it returns an object

```
Related: ["wNs4ByDq7t396WLM3"]
Typeof: object
```

[Related issue](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/369)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope.test` is only bound one time when this code initially runs.  There is no data binding, so even if `$scope.sentence.relatedSentences` changes, `test` will not.  The issue is that `$scope.sentence.relatedSentences` is populated asynchronously.

This would also apply to `$scope.relatedSentences` -- you are trying to set it initially before `$scope.sentence.relatedSentences` is available.  You can use `.subscribe` on the value returned from `.object` to set this once the data is available.

```
$scope.sentence.subscribe().then(function () {
    $scope.relatedSentences = $meteor.collection(function() {
        return Sentences.find({_id: { $in: $scope.sentence.relatedSentences }}); 
    });  
});
```